# Reshape my data according number of zones

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Here is my datas

```
information=structure(list(X = 1:15, Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABL", "ARP"
    ), class = "factor"), Zone = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L), X3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", 
    "Name", "Zone", "X3", "X2", "X5", "X4", "X1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I want for all `Name` Have 12 Zones, when there no `Zone` associated, `Zones` will take the missings values and  the values from X1 to X5 will take 0. Notice for example that for `Name` ARP and ABL I have no zone 3 for each one.

I tried this code

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
    plot_data=information
    plot_data$Zone=(factor(plot_data$Zone, levels = c(1:12)))
    plot_data= plot_data %>%  left_join(data_frame(Zone= factor(1:12)), .)
```

it gives me :

```
     Zone     X   Name    X3    X2    X5    X4    X1
   (fctr) (int) (fctr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1       1     1    ABL     1     0     0     0     0
2       1     9    ARP     3     0     0     0     0
3       2     2    ABL     1     0     0     0     0
4       2    10    ARP     0     0     1     0     0
5       3    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6       4    11    ARP     1     0     0     1     0
7       5    12    ARP     2     0     0     0     0
8       6    13    ARP     0     0     1     0     0
9       7     3    ABL     1     0     0     0     0
10      7    14    ARP     1     0     0     0     0
11      8     4    ABL     1     1     0     0     0
12      9     5    ABL     2     0     0     0     0
13      9    15    ARP     0     1     0     0     0
14     10     6    ABL     2     0     0     0     1
15     11     7    ABL     1     0     0     0     0
16     12     8    ABL     1     0     0     0     0
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we `complete()` the data to make sure all `Name` have all `Zone`. Then, we replace `NA`s with `0` in column `X1` to `X5`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

information %>%
  complete(Name, Zone) %>%
  replace_na(as.list(setNames(rep(0, 5), paste0("X", 1:5))))
```

Which gives:

```
#   Name Zone  X X3 X2 X5 X4 X1
#1   ABL    1  1  1  0  0  0  0
#2   ABL    2  2  1  0  0  0  0
#3   ABL    4 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#4   ABL    5 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#5   ABL    6 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#6   ABL    7  3  1  0  0  0  0
#7   ABL    8  4  1  1  0  0  0
#8   ABL    9  5  2  0  0  0  0
#9   ABL   10  6  2  0  0  0  1
#10  ABL   11  7  1  0  0  0  0
#11  ABL   12  8  1  0  0  0  0
#12  ARP    1  9  3  0  0  0  0
#13  ARP    2 10  0  0  1  0  0
#14  ARP    4 11  1  0  0  1  0
#15  ARP    5 12  2  0  0  0  0
#16  ARP    6 13  0  0  1  0  0
#17  ARP    7 14  1  0  0  0  0
#18  ARP    8 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#19  ARP    9 15  0  1  0  0  0
#20  ARP   10 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#21  ARP   11 NA  0  0  0  0  0
#22  ARP   12 NA  0  0  0  0  0
```

**Note**: As per mentioned by @aosmith you could use the `fill` argument of `complete()` instead (it calls `replace_na` internally):

```
information %>%
  complete(Name, Zone, fill = as.list(setNames(rep(0, 5), paste0("X", 1:5))))
```

---

Notice that this method only `complete()` for observed `Zone`s. Since you don't have `Zone = 3` in your initial data, it won't add this `Name` & `Zone` combination to the result. If you wanted to fill in missing values that should have been observed but weren't you could use `full_seq()`:

```
information %>%
  complete(Zone = full_seq(Zone, period = 1), Name) %>%
  #just another way to replace NA in column X3 to X1
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)), X3:X1)
```

Comment: Nice one didn't know about `complete()` function.

Comment: Any reason not to use the `fill` argument of `complete` instead of `replace_na`?

Comment: @aosmith Nope. The `fill` argument could have indeed be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using lookup data and merge:

```
# lookup data every name has every zone
lookup <- data.frame(expand.grid(c("ABL", "ARP"), 1:12))
colnames(lookup) <- c("Name", "Zone")

# marge and convert NA to 0
res <- merge(lookup, information, by = c("Name", "Zone"), all.x = TRUE)
res[, c(paste0("X", 1:5))][ is.na(res[, c(paste0("X", 1:5))]) ] <- 0
```

Comment: Good idea. Although this way you would also replace the `NA` in the `X` column with `0`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré oops didn't notice it was a requirement , fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
aux_key<-merge(x=unique(information$Name),y=1:12)
    names(aux_key)<-c("Name","Zone")

    new_information<-merge(
      x=aux_key
      ,y=information
      ,by.x=c("Name","Zone")
      ,by.y=c("Name","Zone")
      ,all.x=T
      )
    new_information[is.na(new_information)] <- 0
    new_information[new_information$X==0,"X"] <- NA
    head(new_information)
```